# Is it possible to symbolize a layer with time from now?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.3

Using Arc Desktop 10.3.1 and AGOnline, I have a polygon feature class showing different service zones and the dates of last service.  I would like to symbolize this using a time from now,  ie if it has been more than 1 month since last service date it will be yellow, if it has been more than 2 months it will be orange, etc...  Is there a way to put an expression into the symbology like

if (now) - [last date] > 30  & < 60 then yellow

if (now) - [last date] < 90 & > 60 then orange

etc...

This map will ultimately be used in an ArcGIS Online web map, so it has to be dynamic and constanly updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution assuming your feature class is in a file geodatabase.  I don't know how to do it using ArcGIS Online.  I'm assuming there will be a way similar to what I'm about to propose.

I don't see a way to do this using symbology all by itself.  However, you can create several instances for each of the expressions that you need and put a different definition query on each layer.

Fortunately, file geodatabases support CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  You can put a definition query like the following on each of your layers:

```
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LastDate) >= 30 AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LastDate) < 60
```

And another one like this:

```
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LastDate) >= 60 AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - LastDate) < 90
```

Repeat for however many expressions you need.  Set the symbology appropriately.  This should change dynamically.

*note, I included the `>=` symbol rather than just `>` to include the lower limit.

Comment: I like your idea,  let me experiment with it and see what I can do!

Comment: This works great in Arc,  I havent created the web maps yet with it but I would imagine it will work just fine.  Great Idea!